# List of files loaded in Spark dataset

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage

Suppose we have below file structure
realtime\temp\f1.txt,f2.txt,f3.txt

We have created dataset in spark 2 for these files.
Now after processing these files we need to delete these files from source location (realtime\temp)

so We want list of these all files by which we have created Dataset.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can create a hadoop file system object. Then list of the files in directory.
Once you have the list just iterate over the files to delete them one by one.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

var hfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())

  val allFileIterator = hfs.listFiles(new Path("/user/sngrover"), true)
  while (allFileIterator.hasNext()) {
    val filePath = allFileIterator.next().getPath
    hfs.delete(filePath, false)
 }
```